# Put_connections to create a new event with Koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm trying to create a new event using the Koala gem and it's returning with the same error I got when I tried to update an event with an incorrectly formatted datetime value.

I can update just fine now but still cannot create an event.

Here's the code I use on my update method which works:

```
start_time   = safe_params[:start_time].in_time_zone
end_time     = safe_params[:end_time].in_time_zone

graph.put_connections(safe_params[:fb_id], "event", {
  name: safe_params[:name], 
  description: safe_params[:description], 
  privacy: safe_params[:privacy]
})
```

And here's the code I'm trying to use to create a new event object:

```
graph.put_connections("/me/events", "event", { #this is the line that errors
  name: safe_params[:name], 
  description: safe_params[:description], 
  privacy: safe_params[:privacy]
})
```

According to Facebook's documentation on creating an event (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/), I should be able to create a new event just by initiating a post to /me/events. Anyone have any idea?

I also tried:

```
graph.put_connections("/"+current_user.fb_id.to_s+"/events", "event", {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing with Facebook's Graph Explorer and attempting hundreds of different combinations with put_connections I decided to make a straight graph_call using Koala.

Finally got an ID response back. I almost cried. Thought I'd share with the community in case there's someone else trying to do the same thing.

```
event_response = graph.graph_call("/me/events",{
    name:safe_params[:name], 
    start_time:   safe_params[:start_time], 
    privacy_type: safe_params[:privacy], 
    access_token: current_user.oauth_token}, "POST")
safe_params[:fb_id] << event_response["id"]
@event = Event.create safe_params
```

I make the call in a stored variable event_response because the Facebook Id returned is used in my app.

First thing I found out: despite using "privacy" as the name of the privacy field when GETting from Facebook and saying so in their documentation, "privacy_type" is actually what you want (found this out in another SO post).

The second thing I found out is even though you are authenticated (have a user token) when you make a graph_call you STILL need to pass along the current_user access token along with making a POST graph_call.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do something like this?

```
graph.put_connections("me", "events", {
  name: safe_params[:name], 
  description: safe_params[:description], 
  privacy: safe_params[:privacy],
  start_time: ...,
  end_time: ...
})
```

Comment: Hi @Guy... I still the same type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) Invalid parameter [HTTP 400] error.